# Can't see lowest rated questions

Tags: bug, status-deferred, broken-link, 404-not-found

If I go to the "all questions" page and sort by votes, I'm told there's 1,601,257 pages of questions:

[image]

However, if I click the link to go to the last page, I get a 404 error:

[image]

As questions are posted, the total number of pages goes up every few seconds. However, regardless of how many there are, clicking that last page link always gives a 404.

Comment: Indeed it looks like there's a periodic off by one error specifically on the "Score" sorting option for questions (Regardless of page size). It's possible the number of questions is fluctuating enough the page actually doesn't exist by the time you click it, but getting a 404 on page navigation is definitely not the best user experience.

Comment: @HenryEcker You may be right about the fluctuations. If I hold `Ctrl-R` on the linked URL, I eventually get a page of questions (with "how to send 100,000 emails weekly?" at the bottom), but another refresh will sometimes give a 404. That would explain why this only occurs really on SO due to constant churn of low-quality questions.

Comment: You can use [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=Score%3a..-30%20is%3aq&searchOn=3) (or similar) as a workaround.